# Simple try & catch code for scanning not working with decimal values

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

    try{

        float b = a.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("You wrote " + b);

    }catch(Exception n){

        System.out.println("That wasn't a number, yo!");

    }

    a.close();

}

}
```

I want to scan the number that the user has entered and hence figure out whether it is a number or not. Problems arise when I enter a decimal number such as 3.1415 because it detects it as a non-numerical value.

Comment: What does it do when you enter `3,1415`?

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Could we get a console log?

Comment: What is Arnau really trying to say ? `3.1415` is a number.

Comment: I can run it without errors, so I probably can't help you. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the `Scanner` parses the float depending on your locale. When you use a `,` instead of a `.` it works. For example, in Germany and Austria, it is common to use a `,` as comma, not a `.` so depending on where you are, this might be the case as well.

You can set the locale of the `Scanner` to `US` using:

```
a.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Then you'll have to use `.` again.

Comment: The `Locale` tells the `Scanner` which country-specific formatting conventions should be used.